# Rails - attribute that has not changed has registered as changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

`Order has_many RentalItems`

So I have this callback on `Order` where the point is that the `xyz_method` runs whenever any child `RentalItem` has its `size` or `specification` changed, or a new child `RentalItem` has been added.

```
before_save do
  if rental_items_attributes_modified?
    xyz_method
  end
end

def rental_items_attributes_modified?
  self.rental_items.each do |ri|
    # as long as ONE item had ONE thing changed, we return true or it's a new record
    puts "in RI modified?"
    puts "#{ri.new_record?} with ID #{ri.id}"
    puts "#{ri.specification_changed?} from #{ri.specification_was} to #{ri.specification}"
    puts "#{ri.size_changed?} from #{ri.size_was} to #{ri.size}"
    if ri.specification_changed? || ri.size_changed? || ri.new_record?
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

All the `puts` were helping me debug... I have no idea why but `rental_items_attributes_modified?` keeps returning true, because for ONE of the `RentalItems`, the `specification_changed?` returns `true` even though it's not... This is the relevant log output:

```
# testing the first child RI
in RI modified?
false with ID 1
false from blue to blue
false from Regular to Regular

# testing the second child RI
in RI modified?
false with ID 2
true from  to # <<< why is this happening???
false from Regular to Regular
```

For the weird second child `RI` in question, `specification = ""` initially, and what gets passed are params like this:

```
"rental_items_attributes"=>[{"id"=>"2", "specification"=>"", "size"=>"Regular"}]
```

I have tried this standalone in the console, and it triggers the correct behavior...

```
# for an order whose child RI initially had a blank specification & size
o.update_attributes({"rental_items_attributes" => [{"id" => 79, "specification" => ""}]})
=>
in RI modified?
false with ID 79
false from  to 
false from  to
```

Comment: Is there a default value for `specification`?  This may be an issue of nil vs. "".

Comment: I looked into it, had the same suspicion, it's not the issue; `specification` starts as `""` when the child is first created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a comment, but I can't write a comment due to less reputation.
(Thus, you can ignore this comment.)

Have you ever checked values in before_save block? Like,

```
ri.specification_was.nil?
ri.specification.nil?
```

Both are false?

Comment: OMG i'm so stupid... so my response to John Feltz was that `nil` was not the problem, and I was absolutely sure of that. your answer made me want to double check so I did, and it turns out one of the instances was reading as `nil` so then when I went a bit crazy and dug into why it turns out there was a GODDAMN TYPO and I had passed something like `speciification => ""` so the param never hit the DB! UGH